# Close all temporary buffers automatically in emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer

How can we close temporary buffers which are enclosed with * automatically. For e.g. *messages*, *completions* buffer needs to be closed. Killing all these buffers manually after use is painful.

Is there a way to close temporary buffers created by emacs (not by us)?

Comment: Killing `*Messages*` and `*Minibuffer*` is pointless and quite possibly dangerous in some situations. Why do you care about these buffers for internal use, anyway? Under most circumstances, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need to close those buffers? If you use a [proper buffer switching method](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers) like iswitchb then you don't have to care about temporary or other buffers, because you can go directly to any buffer you want.

Answer (score 3):

I'd second the suggestion you use `ido` or `iswitchb` to avoid being bothered by temporary buffers. The presence of those buffers is a natural consequence of using emacs, so don't try to swim upstream!

On the other hand, if you're irritated by the growing list of open buffers, you can use `midnight.el` to automatically close inactive buffers after a period of time, or you can use `ibuffer` to easily select and close unwanted buffers en masse.

Personally, I leave buffers open for a long time, I tidy them up occasionally using `ibuffer`, and I rely on `ido` to switch buffers quickly. In Emacs 24, you can set `ido-use-virtual-buffers` to `t`, and then `ido` will let you switch to closed files, reopening them as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As [user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11914795/1419272) said, it would be better to use a smart buffer-switching package such as `iswitchb` and `ido`. `iswitchb`'s `iswitchb-buffer-ignore` and `ido`'s `ido-ignore-buffers` variables allow us to specify what buffers to ignore using regular expressions.

However, if you really want to ***kill*** those buffers, a program like this will be helpful to you:

```lisp
(require 'cl)

(defvar kill-star-buffers-except
  '("\\`\\*scratch\\*\\'"
    "\\`\\*Messages\\*\\'"
    "\\` \\*Minibuf-[[:digit:]]+\\*\\'"
    "\\` \\*Echo Area [[:digit:]]+\\*\\'")
  "Exception list for `kill-star-buffers'")

(defun kill-star-buffers ()
  "Kill all star buffers except those in `kill-star-buffers-except'"
  (interactive)
  (mapc (lambda (buf)
          (let ((buf-name (buffer-name buf)))
            (when (and
                   ;; if a buffer's name is enclosed by * with optional leading
                   ;; space characters
                   (string-match-p "\\` *\\*.*\\*\\'" buf-name)
                   ;; and the buffer is not associated with a process
                   ;; (suggested by "sanityinc")
                   (null (get-buffer-process buf))
                   ;; and the buffer's name is not in `kill-star-buffers-except'
                   (notany (lambda (except) (string-match-p except buf-name))
                           kill-star-buffers-except))
              (kill-buffer buf))))
        (buffer-list)))
```

Comment: You'd probably also want to avoid killing buffers which return non-nil for `(get-buffer-process)`, such as compilation or repl buffers.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having those buffers in your way, you could define key-bindings to cycle through «user buffers» and «useless buffers» :

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/effective_emacs.html , section «Switching Next/Previous User Buffers»

but some useful buffers start with a *, like shells, compilation buffer, ielm, etc.